# on() vs live() click function on element that doesn't exist yet

Tags: jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

As far as I know, the `click()` method isn't working for me because the element I'm clicking does not exist on page load (DOM ready).

I've found many answers suggesting to use `.live('click',function(){...})`. This works great!

However, `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7

So, I've tried using `.on('click',function(){...})` instead, but it doesn't not work (acts the same as `.click()`.

Does anyone know why, or what I can do to use `.on()` similarly to `.live()` (which works) ?

Comment: @wrschneider99 yes indeed!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since `on()` replaces both `bind()` and `live()`, you need to pass a third parameter in order to make use of event delegation (in other words, to make it work like the old `live()`):

```
$('#container').on('click', '.element', function(){ });
```

Comment: Thanks, what if `#container` is the same element as `.element` ? I've tried using the same element in both places, but no luck :/

Comment: @iight Then it wont work. `#container` cant be dynamically generated. As j08691 said, pick a wrapping element as close to the dynamically added element as possible to improve performance.

Comment: must be a parent element, though, right?

Comment: @iight Correct. A parent element which is not dynamically generated, and as close as possible in the DOM.

Comment: @iight Np, glad to help!

Comment: FYI    Inside the function, $(this) will be equal to $('.element'), not $('#container')

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use a format like this:

```
$(document).on('click','element', function(){...});
```

Where `element` is the element you want to bind the click event to. Using `document` is kind of a worst-case scenario since you ideally want to use an element that exists when the DOM is loaded that is closer in the DOM hierarchy to the element that will be dynamically loaded.

From the jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) docs:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Comment: Thanks! this works, but now I just have to research the whole $(document) binding. This does fix the issue though!